# Oxygen sensor up to 50%

Tags: sensors

Are there any oxygen sensors that measure up to 50%?.

As I understand, there are sensors that measure only in range 0-30%.

Is it possible to increase the threshold of sensitivity of the sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [SO002](http://www.sensore-electronic.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/SO002e-3_Data-sheet-sensor.pdf) or [DS-TR250](http://www.co2meters.com/Documentation/Datasheets/DS-TR250Z-sensor.pdf).

> Is it possible to increase the threshold of sensitivity of the sensor?

I don't think its possible. Perhaps you can tweak the reading sensitivity, but since the sensor are mostly analog, it's not possible. And maybe that also the reason the 2 sensors I've mentioned above have several series based on their measuring threshold.

Answer (score 0):

The Bosh LSU 4.X sensor(s) are what I think you are looking for. Here are some related links:

http://www.waltech.com/open-source-designs/wbo2_report/

https://github.com/Hell-Fire/WidebandO2